# Laravel Scheduler Custom Cron Expression Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I've got two laravel scheduler expression calls as follows: One with a custom cron expression which runs every 3 hours and another hourly.

Every time, the hourly scheduler runs, but not the custom cron one. It used to work, but stopped working. If I call Poster1::post() directly from any function, it works though.

Can explain to me why this is not working, when it was earlier?

First Scheduler:

```
    $schedule->call(function () {
        try {
            Poster1::post();                
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    })->cron('0 */3 * * *');
```

Second Scheduler:

```
    $schedule->call(function () {
        try {
            Poster2::post();                
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    })->hourly();
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of the code. What you might do is actually debug something in the (currently empty) `catch` block. Also, debugging before the `try` could tell you if the job is even triggered.

Comment: Verify if the cron job is getting executed first by adding a log when it's run. Might as well add one in the catch block to see if there's any exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Laravel scheduler functions to run every 3 hours.

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    try {
        Poster1::post();                
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
})
->hourly()
->when(function() { 
    return intval(date('H')) % 3 === 0;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'm going to try this and report back :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this answer as the solution so other users might find this as well. :)

Comment: Works great! Thanks!